# Arduino: if-compare parameters

Tags: c++, c, embedded, arduino

I'm trying to get a small BMP085 barometer project up and running. I want to be able to switch between different modes of operation (MODE_PRESSURE and MODE_ALT). I have `MODE_PRESSURE` and `MODE_ALT` defined as `const int`.

```
const int MODE_PRESSURE = 1;  // display pressure and temp
const int MODE_ALT      = 2;  // display altitude relative to sea level
int mode;                     // stores the current mode

void setup {
    mode = MODE_PRESSURE;
}

void loop {

    // Read mode button and set mode accordingly
    int buttonPressed = readButtons();

    switch(buttonPressed) {
    case BTN_MODE:
        if(mode == MODE_PRESSURE) { mode = MODE_ALT; }
        if(mode == MODE_ALT) { mode = MODE_PRESSURE; }
        Serial.println(mode); // <<-- always prints 1 ?!
        break;
    }
}
```

When the mode button is pressed, I want to toggle the current mode. But I'm stuck at `if(mode == MODE_PRESSURE)`. This statement somehow never evaluates to true...?

I'm not very fluent in C, is there something I am missing? Can I not compare `const int` and `int` variables?

P.S.: I've also tried `#define` for MODE_PRESSURE and MODE_ALT, and `const byte`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `else` as follows:

```
    if(mode == MODE_PRESSURE)  
       mode = MODE_ALT; 
    else if(mode == MODE_ALT) # although not need but keep if here also
       mode = MODE_PRESSURE;
```

You could *also* use nested-switch:

```
switch(mode){
     case MODE_PRESSURE: mode = MODE_ALT; 
             break; 

     case MODE_ALT: mode = MODE_PRESSURE; 
             break;
}
```

Comment: Aaahhhhgggrr, of course. I must have been sleeping! Thanks, will try tonight when home again.

Comment: @Elmer Consider whether or not you would have written this bug if you had put the body of an if statement on a line of its own, with proper indention.

Comment: @Lundin I actually had it on multiple lines before, but tried all sorts of things. It's just one of those days (nights) where a bit of sleep would have helped. A well, you win some, you loose some :)

Answer (score 4):

You are resetting the mode back to pressure every time.  Change your if statement to

```
if (mode == MODE_PRESSURE)
    mode = MODE_ALT;
else
    mode = MODE_PRESSURE:
```

Alternatively, if you want a one liner either

```
mode = mode == MODE_PRESSURE ? MODE_ALT: MODE_PRESSURE;
```

or

```
mode = MODE_PRESSURE + MODE_ALT - mode;
```

Comment: +1 for the one line alternative, but consider using xor: `0x03 ^ mode` (returns `0` if `mode != 1 && mode != 2`)

Comment: Yes - that is always the problem with one liners: when the value isn't one of the two specified.  There are lots of methods of switching between two values, some very expensive like mode = 2 / mode.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are assigning the mode to ALT when mode equals to PRESSURE. But you are not using any break statement so it will again set the mode to PRESSURE in the second if condition.

Here is the Sample Solution to your code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int BTN_MODE = 0;
const int MODE_PRESSURE = 1;    // display pressure and temp
const int MODE_ALT = 2; // display altitude relative to sea level
int mode;   // stores the current mode

void setup()
{
    mode = MODE_PRESSURE;
}

void loop()
{

    // Read mode button and set mode accordingly
    // int buttonPressed = readButtons();
    int buttonPressed = BTN_MODE;

    switch (buttonPressed)
    {
        case 0:
            if (mode == MODE_PRESSURE)
            {
                mode = MODE_ALT;
                break;
            }
            if (mode == MODE_ALT)
            {
                mode = MODE_PRESSURE;
                break;
            }
            //Serial.println(mode); // <<-- always prints 1 ?!
            break;
    }
    printf(" The mode value is : %d\n", mode);
}

void main()
{
    setup();
    loop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` sets `mode` to `MODE_ALT`. This will force second `if` to always be `true`.

Add `else` to second test:

```
else if(mode == MODE_ALT) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "else" between the two ifs. Try stepping Your code in Your head and You will see that if the first if was true, the second one will be true, too, and sets MODE_PRESSURE.